Gallery Items Do Not Stack Properly When Using Different Widths
There are many options to create galleries of pictures where items stack neatly on top of each other - most of them are quite old, such as isotope.js or masonry, an old jquery library:
They achieve something which looks like the screenshot below, no problem.

The problem starts however, when you get items of differing widths. They stack but in an ugly way, with large gaps between the items.
My question is:
Do you know of any way, using Masonry or pure CSS or Javascript which fixes irregular stacking?

asking for tools is off topic here

Thank you Temani, you've been very helpful.
